# How to test for a correlation when no paired data is available?

Tags: regression, correlation, random-effects-model

This is a question that came up in my allometry research: I am interested in estimating the  correlation between 2 characteristics of red blood cells, let's call them A and B, across multiple mammals (from "mouse to elephant"). Their measurement is cumbersome / expensive. Reviewing the literature. I found several papers where A was measured in about 20 mammal species (mice; rats; cats; dogs; humans; ...) and several papers where B was measured in the same mammal species (mice; rats; cats; dogs; humans; ...). However, **I could not find a single paper** where a pair of A and B was measure in the same animal.
I am now thinking about the following approach:
(a) Estimate the distribution (mean; SD) of A and B on a species level (separately for mice; rats; ...).
(b) Randomly sample from the the species-specific distribution of A and B, respectively, and create A-B pairs
(c) Run a mixed effects model across ALL species using the species-level pairs created as described in (b) to estimate the correlation of A and B across all species.
Is this a valid approach? Thank you all for reflecting on my question.